# Remove image from custom photo album

Tags: ios, iphone, alassetslibrary, alasset

Is there a way to remove an image from a custom photo album?
I don't want to permanently delete the asset from the phone but just simply disassociate x image from x album.

I am trying to build an application that automatically manages certain photo albums.
In some cases images would need to be removed from photo albums and added to others.
I am currently using the ALAssetsLibrary to create photo albums and add images to them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no public API to remove an image from a custom/user created album. If you want that feature in the future, request it at https://feedbackassistant.apple.com/.